# Locking required in read only scenarios when using decimal?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm doing some regression analysis in C# and get weird results when not locking read access to my function values. Sure, initially locking access to the x and y values when reading them could solve the problem but I'd like to know why this seems to be necessary? Or is this just a misbehavior in my scenario? In this case I could isolate the failing code and post it here, too.

Ok, so here now the code part failing, when removing the used lock:

```
foreach (var fv in functionValues)
{
    decimal x, y;

    lock(o)
    {
        if (!firstX.HasValue) { firstX = paramNormalizationFactorX.HasValue ? fv.X : 0; }

        x = (fv.X - firstX.Value) * factorX;
        y = fv.Y;
    }

    var xx = x * x;
    var xxx = xx * x;
    var xxxx = xxx * x;
}
```

functionValues is a shared list of value pairs. When not locking I sooner or later get a overflow exception because of weird x values.

Comment: Posting code would go a long way.

Comment: How many threads are running this code?

Comment: In my scenario there are 4 threads running this code - but I guess that doesn't matter. I'm going to post a compilable program.cs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my fault: expectedly there is no problem in a read only scenario. In my case the "X"-values had lazy getters calculation the value on the first access. So this actually just wasnt a read only scenario.